# locally disabled is enabled online

Tags: html, google-app-engine

My simple app is designed to start with a button disabled and then change to enabled when user completes a task successfully. This works locally, but not on the deployed app. On the deployed app the button starts enabled.

Python code:

```
pbndata = ''

class MainPage(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
    global pbndata
    logging.info("pbn pbndata length in get: %s " % len(pbndata))
    if len(pbndata) > 0:
        buttonclass = 'button'
    else:
        buttonclass = 'button disabled'
    template_values = {'buttonclass':buttonclass}
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

Template code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div id="boards" style="margin: auto;max-width: 700px; position: relative;  top: 0px; background-color: #808080" >
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item middle">(0) Supply your .pbn URL</div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <form action=""   method="Post">
    <button  
        id="Deal" class="{{ buttonclass }}" style="display: inline-block;background-color: #0000ff; float:right"
        {% if buttonclass == "button disabled" %}
        disabled
        {% endif %}
        >
    Deals
    </button>
</form>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Online `view-source` notice the attribute `disabled` is omitted:

```
    <form action=""   method="Post">
    <button  
        id="Deal" class="button" style="display: inline-block;background-color: #0000ff; float:right"

        >
    Deals
    </button>
</form>
```

Local `view-source` notice the attribute `disabled` is present:

```
<form action=""   method="Post">
    <button  
        id="Deal" class="button disabled" style="display: inline-block;background-color: #0000ff; float:right"

        disabled

        >
    Deals
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: The length of pbndata varies in my logs, so far only between 0 and 20719 because the app is very new and only I and maybe one other person have exercised it. So my app does modifies the value of pbndata. I **expect** each new login to set `pbndata=''` but the problem may be that there is no user login and no user identification in my app; everyone gets the same templates and executable on my gae app. Is the problem that the app is not reinitialized for each new login and page refresh? I can post parts of the logs to the question, I guess. If this is the problem, I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

`pbndata` is a module level variable.  App Engine modules are initialised when an instance is started, and remain in memory until the instance is terminated.  The value of `pbndata` is likely to be empty only until the first visitor "completes a task", and will be non-empty from then on.

Note if you have multiple active instances, each instance will load a distinct copy of your module, so the value of `pbndata` will be different on each instance.

If you want to maintain per-user state (that is, a distinct `pbndata` for each user) without implementing a login system the solution is to [set](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/response.html#setting-cookies) and [retrieve](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/request.html#guide-request-cookies) cookies.  You can store the value of `pbndata` in the cookie.

This is simple to implement but insecure, as a malicious user could tamper with the value stored in the cookie.  A more secure approach would be to store the value of `pbndata` in a [session](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html), and store the session key in the cookie.

Comment: This issue came up because I was trying to prepare a screencast explaining my own app to other potential users and I was not able to force the app to its original starting state on my computer which had pbndata=''. I did not understand how to force that original state to exist again on my own computer using gae. That is, I did not know how to make my app "terminate" or "complete a task." All I needed to do was to quit my browser(s) and restart. So I think your solution is likely correct, but is not necessary for me because the empty value for pbndata is not required after the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

I could find no way with code to force my app to reinitialize even by quitting the open browser and surfing again to the link. That seemed to work if the connection is dead for a few hours, because then gae might reinitialize the application. But I wanted a dependable reset.

So I settled on a sort of easter egg solution because the reinitialization is not required for normal satisfactory use of the app. I changed a link in another template of the app from the commented out `<a  >` link to the `<form  >` post shown below.

```
<!--a href="/" style="background-color: #808080" target="_self">New boards</a-->
<form action="" method="Post">
  <button id="Newboards" class="button" style="display: inline-block;background-color: #808080; float:left" >
    New Boards
  </button>
  <input type="hidden" id="newboard" name="newboard" value="True" />
</form>
<!--a href="/" style="background-color: #808080" target="_self">New boards</a-->
```

Then in the python I altered the following Post definition which reset the value of `pbndata` as desired.

```
   def post(self):
    global Cards
    global Suits
    global pbndata
        newboard = self.request.get('newboard', None)
    if newboard:
        pbndata=''
        return webapp2.redirect('/')
    Cards = self.request.get('Cards')
    Suits = self.request.get('Suits')
    return webapp2.redirect('/elsewhere')
```

This is an easter egg in the sense that it is an undocumented (and unnecessary for most users) feature.